# Setting hidden value from button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, hidden

I need to set the hidden input value when a button is clicked and it does not seem to be working.

```
<input type="hidden" name="addressOverride" id="addressOverride" value="">
```

Then the button

```
<button id="addressOverrideLink" class="global-button">Yes this is my correct delivery address</button>
```

And the code that is trying to set it

```
if ($('#addressOverrideLink'))
    {
        $('#addressOverrideLink').click(function(e){
            $('#addressOverride').val('YES');
            $('#mainForm').submit();
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use plain JavaScript to do it

```
document.getElementById('addressOverride').value = "YES";
```

Or if you want to use jQuery, do it like this

```
$('input[name=addressOverride]').val('YES');
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/xM5E7/

Answer (score 0):

You should check the length property of the jQuery object in your condition.

Answer (score 0):

That...should work. Only think I can suggest is to do this instead:

```
if($('#addressOverrideLink').length > 0){
/* other stuff here */
}
```